# Pip warning: Could not find project directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Today, I was doing a `pip freeze` (without any virtual environment), and pip showed the warning that:
`WARNING: Could not find a Python project for directory <c:\users\user\pycharmprojects\proj_dir>`.

What does this mean?

Note: I have googled this question.

Here is the terminal output:

```
C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\proj_dir>pip freeze
WARNING: Could not find a Python project for directory c:\users\user\pycharmprojects\proj_dir (tried all parent directories)
anyio==4.1.0
arrow==1.3.0
binaryornot==0.4.4
certifi==2023.11.17
chardet==5.2.0
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
click==8.1.7
colorama==0.4.6
cookiecutter==2.5.0
flet==0.15.0
flet-core==0.15.0
flet-runtime==0.15.0
h11==0.14.0
httpcore==0.17.3
httpx==0.24.1
idna==3.6
Jinja2==3.1.2
markdown-it-py==3.0.0
MarkupSafe==2.1.3
mdurl==0.1.2
oauthlib==3.2.2
packaging==23.2
Pygments==2.17.2
pypng==0.20220715.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-slugify==8.0.1
PyYAML==6.0.1
qrcode==7.4.2
repath==0.9.0
requests==2.31.0
rich==13.7.0
setuptools==69.0.2
six==1.16.0
sniffio==1.3.0
-e git+https://github.com/taaaf11/Ta-Do.git@a2c510d9d85371bf01f6ca88d49e1dfd29c2425e#egg=Ta_Do
text-unidecode==1.3
types-python-dateutil==2.8.19.14
typing_extensions==4.9.0
urllib3==2.1.0
watchdog==3.0.0
websocket-client==1.7.0
websockets==11.0.3
```

Expectation: I wasn't expecting a warning.

**Things that may help**
-> There's a virtual environment in the shown directory.
-> It does not show the warning when the virtual environment of the directory is activated.

Comment: It might help to show your full stack trace

Comment: @journpy How to get full stack trace? I mean, I can't understand your comment

Comment: this is not an error in the script. It is warning in `pip freeze`

Comment: `-e git+https://github.com/taaaf11/Ta-Do.git@a2c510d9d85371bf01f6ca88d49e1dfd29c2425e#egg=Ta_Do` is trying to install this [tree](https://github.com/taaaf11/Ta-Do/tree/a2c510d9d85371bf01f6ca88d49e1dfd29c2425e) but failed — there're no `setuptools` files. Could it be the warning is related to this? I wonder how does `pip freeze` list the package? Perhaps you have done something locally to install it?

Comment: I removed all the packages (I think I deleted the venv, can't remember), till `pip freeze` showed nothing (I think the package deletion was due to reinstalling python, can't remember). Now I installed `package-python-hello-world` for testing, and it is not showing the warning. I think the warning was related to this. I was creating myself a package. `pip install -e .`-ed it.

Comment: @tofi1130 glad you've resolved it

Comment: @phd just a quick question. what is stack trace? Is it the "Traceback ..." thing when an exception occurs?

Comment: @taafuuu__ Yes. To be precise — a Python script prints stack trace when an **unhandled** exception occurred and the interpreter terminates the script. What you put into the the question is normal output from `pip freeze`, not a stack trace.